# Insert Query giving Error

Tags: php, mysql, html, insert

Below is my SQL Query for insertion in Mysql DB

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $db_table(area,schemetype,schemesector,year,desc) 
 values  ('".$_REQUEST['area']."','".$_REQUEST['schemetype']."',
         '".$_REQUEST['s   chemesector']."','".$_REQUEST['year']."',
         '".$_REQUEST['desc']."')";
```

the Above query is giving error the error is about Cant use desc in keys

Regards

Comment: write the $sql variable output and the table column datatypes so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: what is the error? please provide such information as it helps in debugging.

Comment: please post your error AND the content of `$sql`

Comment: Please research on how to format your code properly. At first glance it looks like you have an `if` statement with two `else` conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DESC` is reserved world in Mysql. use backticks (`) around it in query while using it as column name.

Try below :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $db_table(area,schemetype,schemesector,year,`desc`) values  ('".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['area']))."','".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['schemetype']))."','".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['schemesector']))."','".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['year']))."','".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['desc']))."')";
```

Comment: im sorry the code was not properly formatted but u catch it

Comment: Never mind: Keep it up :). Be awrae for next post